# Converting WPF to .XBAP doesn't work!

Tags: asp.net, wpf, xbap

Hello
 I want to integrate WPF with ASP.NET project I read about this problem, and I know I have to convert the WPF project to .xbap I tried to follow this http://www.xbap.org/tutorial.html on two projects :

1- as a test on a WPFBrowserApplication : the result was
 just a .xbap file when i run it a local host web page opened with " Hello XBAP "

but I want to convert the following WPF app

2- on this one https://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx I put the
 good from Step 4 it just gave me thr " Hello XBAP" on the WPF grid and run as a desktop app 
even I changed every thing in xaml and xaml.cs from Window to Page

I really need help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tutorial:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/11/120718.html

Answer (score 0):

To convert a page-based application to XBAP you set values for 4 key tags in the .vbproj file

1.If you want to Host the application in a web browser you can set the HostInBroser tag to True
2.You set the Install tag to False to prevent installation of XBAP on a computer.  Setting this tag to False also caches the application in the Temporary Internet Files Folder 
3.The ApplicationExtension tag sets .xbap as the extension of the application file.
4.You use the TargetZone tag to set the Internet security level of the application.